# Use ST_Distance() to filter a maximum of distances

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, st-distance

I've tried to select only the schools/kindergarten that are maximum 1000m distant from the train station. Here is my code

```
SELECT gebaeude.name AS "Name", 
ST_Distance(geom,(SELECT geom FROM gebaeude 
WHERE gebaeude.osm_id='159867730' )) AS "Distanz" 
FROM gebaeude WHERE gebaeude_salzburg.type='school'
OR gebaeude.type='kindergarten' and "Distanz" <= 1000;
```

Where do I have to place the condition so that it works?

Comment: Which projection are you using? What does "it doesn't work" mean (error message, too many results, not all results, else)?

Answer (score 1):

You had better to use CTE (Common Table Expression) to make your query readable. If you have spatial index on geom column then the ST_DWITHIN function is more effective. I suppose you forget to put brackets around the OR condition in WHERE.

```
WITH center AS (
    SELECT geom FROM gebaeude_salzburg 
    WHERE osm_id='159867730'
)
SELECT gebaeude_salzburg.name AS "Name der Einrichtung",
    ST_Distance(gebaeude_salzburg.geom, center.geom) as "Distanz"
FROM gebaeude_salzburg, center
WHERE (gebaeude_salzburg.type='school' OR
    gebaeude_salzburg.type='kindergarten') AND
    ST_DWITHIN(gebaeude_salzburg.geom, center.geom, 1000.0);
```

Comment: Yes, select ST_Buffer(geom, 1000, 'quad_segs=80') in the first part (center),  the third parameter is the number of segments to approximate circle, the default is 8 (I think it too low). Instead ST_DWithin you should use ST_Within for the point and the buffer.

Comment: Instead of the OR condition you can use
gebaeude_salzburg.type in ('school', 'kindergarten')

Comment: Please add an alias to ST_BUFFER(geom, 1000, ...) as geom.